# Redirect to another server using apache virtual-Host reverse-proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I have a server running on Ubuntu. I can access to that server via reverse proxy with Apache. Now comes the stuff I want to do. I want to redirect to another server (not the same machine) when requested those uris:

- /osimis-viewer/app/index.html?study={ID}
- /osimis-viewer/app/index.html?series={ID}
- /web-viewer/app/viewer.html?series={ID}

The Uri must be the same, so if I request `localhost/osimis-viewer/app/index.html?study={ID}` I should be redirected to `new-ip/osimis-viewer/app/index.html?study={ID}`
I am trying to do it via mod_rewrite, but I am not getting it to work.
Some help would be appreciated.

The config file in sites-enabled is something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProcyRequests Off
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8042/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8042/"
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/orthanc-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/orthanc-access.log combined
    LogLevel error
    // Some tries with RewriteRule
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  probably that you appended your additional reverse proxy settings after the the more inclusive `ProxyPass "/"` directive and therefore they were never applicable.
ProxyPass rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins, so try:

Try:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass "/osimis-viewer/app/index.html" "http://new-ip/osimis-viewer/app/index.html" 
  ProxyPassReverse "/osimis-viewer/app/index.html" "http://new-ip/osimis-viewer/app/index.html"  

  ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8042/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8042/"

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/orthanc-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/orthanc-access.log combined
  LogLevel error
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is extrange. Not working how i expected. It is supposed to redirect me to the other server (with the image with the {ID} in its database) but it does not show me the image. However, I'm asked the login of that server. I'm totally lost on this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work, at least for now. This is the config now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} series [OR]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} study
  Rewriterule "^/osimis-viewer/app/index.html" "http://10.8.0.11:8042/osimis-vi$
  Rewriterule "^/web-viewer/app/viewer.html" "http://10.8.0.11:8042/web-viewer/$

  ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8042/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:8042/"

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/orthanc-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/orthanc-access.log combined
  LogLevel error
</VirtualHost>
```